# Add UINavigationBar inside view and show buttons

Tags: ios

I have viewController. Inside is I have `UIView`

```
lazy var cView : UIView = {
    var view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    return view
}()
```

Inside this view I have `UINavigationBar`

```
lazy var navigationBar : UINavigationBar = {
    let bar = UINavigationBar()
    let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(cancel))
    bar.topItem?.setLeftBarButton(leftButton, animated: true)
    let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(done))
    bar.topItem?.setRightBarButton(rightButton, animated: true)
    bar.barTintColor = .green
    bar.tintColor = UIColor.red
    bar.barStyle = .default
    bar.isTranslucent = false
    return bar
}()
```

The problem is that in viewController I see only red view with green bar and without any buttons.

What am I doing wrong ? How to make buttons visible ?

Answer (score 0):

bar.topItem UINavigationItem is nil when UINavigationBar is initialized. You can use bar.setItems(items: [UINavigationItem]?, animated: Bool) method to set bar.topItem

Comment: I think this should work: 


`bar.setItems([UINavigationItem()], animated: false)


bar.topItem?.setLeftBarButton(leftButton, animated: true) `